# .env file does not exists in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

code: public/index.php

```
<?php
    // $path = base_path() . '/.env';
    if(file_exists('/../.env'))
    {
        echo "yes";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No";
    }
```

In this code, I have `.env` file in my root directory but when I try to know my `.env` file exists or not then it shows `No`. I had also tried with `base_path()` after this it throws `500 error`. I don't know why? So, How can I fix this issue? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: you sure the path is correct?

Comment: yes, I am sure @Areg

Comment: it's better to figure out why base_path() is not working. In your code definitely you get wrong result because you start path with slash '/'. You can try change it to './../.env' (add dot at the beginning) or play more with path value, but this is not the best idea to reuse this code, because your path is relative to working directory

Comment: You need to use absolute path. Not relative path.  Try `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . /folder_name/.env`.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes some IDE dont show the .env file. Its hidden in project .

In laravel, search .env.example file .

you can do following step in cmd or terminal (in your project folder)

cp .env.example .env

php artisan key:generate

Comment: Thank you! This has been helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Put below in your routes:

```php
Route::get('/test', function() {
    $path = __DIR__ . '/../.env';
    if(file_exists($path))
    {
        return '<h1>Yes</h1>';
    }
    return '<h1>No</h1>';
});
```

and try visiting the link like `example.com/test`.

> **Note:** For security reasons, `Laravel`'s `.htaccess` file should not allow you to run your script without route.

---

But if you are sure it is removed you could create it like the `.env` file template below:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

then run:

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: This solved my issue. thanks @Top-Master

Comment: @KennedyOwusu note that `APP_DEBUG=true` is a backdoor, which allows people to `SSH` into your server (so ensure to set that to `false`, once published on Ubuntu server).

Comment: okay. thanks @Top-Master